# WPF looks different for a .net 3.5 project after installing .net 4.5 on my system

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have a user interface which is targeted to use .Net 3.5. In this user interface there are some graphical issues (sliders have a stair-step effect, some text is skewed) and this is caused (so I've been told) by my new graphics card assuming .Net 4.0 is installed. This calls some function which has (since 3.5) been altered/improved, however in the 3.5 it behaves differently than the graphics card assumes, and therefore renders the responses incorrectly.

In an attempt to fix this issue I decided to upgrade my project to utilize .Net 4.5 due to several large WPF improvements.

Upon installing .Net 4.5 on my system, however, I immediately saw my graphical issues disappear, BEFORE I changed my project to target .Net 4.5.

Does anyone know what is going on? This is a very troubling side effect that was completely unanticipated; my project says it's utilizing 3.5, but it's rendering as if it's using 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

.Net 4.5 is not side-by-side with .Net 4.0 .
It will actually replace 4.0.

On channel 9 I have listened to an interview from the BCL team where they promise that it would do so 
without any side effects (or at least no bad side effects)

But for WPF there obviously is some Changes.
In Your case it is for the better - at least when somebody is installing .Net 4.5 it will be better.
I have a case where it is good in .Net 4 and looks bad in .Net 4.5 - so I hope my clients don't update
before I find a solution ...

But I understand that Your problem for the moment has more priority ...

Below link to: .NET 4.5: BCL Team - Improvements and Evolution

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/NET-45-Conversation-with-the-BCL-Team-Improvements-Evolution-and-More

Comment: That's an interesting video, though they unfortunately didn't really go in depth on WPF. Thanks for the link though.